# RXJS: Combining multiple calls from foreach into a single observable

Tags: angular, loops, foreach, rxjs, observable

I've been trying to combine multiple async calls for a while now, and everytime I get close, I get stuck at a foreach loop I'm trying to solve.

At the moment I pass an array of categories to a function, which will return an observable containing an array of all the questions (of all the categories combined).
I was thinking of

```js
  getQuestions(categories: Category[]): Observable<Question[]> {
    let q: Question[];
    categories.forEach(c => {
      this.cs
        .getQuestionsCategory(c.id)
        .pipe(map(questions => q.push(...questions)));
         //return q somehow?
    });
  }
```

I would then be able to use it like this:

```js
   let result: Result;
    let res: [Category[], Account, Answer[]];

    return this.getResultByRouteParamId(route).pipe(
      tap(resu => (result = resu)),
      switchMap((result: Result) =>
        this.forkJoinQuizCategoriesAccountAnswers(result)
      ),
      tap(results => (res = results)),
      switchMap(x => this.getQuestions(res[0])),
      map(questions => {
        // Create objects of questions, answers and category and add them to a QuestionAnswer object
        // Return new UserResult containing the user and a list of QuestionAnswer objects
        return new UserResult(null, null);
      })
    );
```

This is as close as I could get to someone's recommendation on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60546308/return-nested-forkjoins-as-observable). I wanted to add this to my original question, but I feel this wouldn't be the right thing to do since I'm no longer struggling with nested observables, but rather with looping over them.

**EDIT**
Tried something else, but I doubt this is the right way to do it

```js
  getQuestions(categories: Category[]): Observable<Question[]> {
    let ques = categories.map(c =>
      this.cs.getQuestionsCategory(this.auth.token, c.id)
    );

    return merge(...ques);
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I like the idea of putting this into a dedicated function, so that you can separate the interface from the implementation.

The problem you want to solve should be doable in the pipe, it's just a case of working out what's going on.

- You start off with an array of `Category`.
- For each catgory, you want to call a service function, which returns an observable array of `Question`.
- You want to return that flattened array of questions from the function asynchronously

I would approach this by:

- Creating the observable array. This helps you understand what you're starting with
- `forkJoin` the observable array. By itself this will return a 2-dimensional array
- `map` the 2-dimensional array to a flat array

```js
getQuestions(categories: Category[]): Observable<Question[]> {
  // firstly, start out with an array of observable arrays
  const observables: Observable<Question[]>[] = categories.map(cat => 
    this.cs.getQuestionsCategory(cat.id));

  // run all observables in parallel with forkJoin
  return forkJoin(
    observables
  ).pipe(
    // now map the array of arrays to a flattened array
    map(questions => this.flat(questions))
  );
}

// alternative to arr.flat()
private flat<T>(arr: T[][]): T[] {
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
}
```

Comment: Is flat() part of a newer version of typescript? It doesn't seem to get recognized

Comment: flat() is an array function. It probably means `questions` isn't an actual array. Or you're using an old browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat You can use `reduce` instead of `flat`. I'll update my answer

Comment: It recognizes question as Question[][]. According to the link you posted, it seems like it is part of a newer version of ES, I'll try to update it to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I've amended my answer to use `reduce`. If this still doesn't get recognized, it might be that `questions` isn't an actual array

Comment: Of course, it doesn't need to be in its own function. The implication here is that you could expose it as a common function. Or you could always include a `flat` polyfill if you wanted to.

Comment: That solved it, must've been something wrong with my ES settings

Comment: You should change tsconfig `lib` property to `ES6` for `flat` to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should combine those streams with `forkJoin` or `combineLatest`:

```
getQuestions(categories: Category[]): Observable<Question[]> {
    return forkJoin(
        categories.map(category => this.cd.getQuestionsCategory(category.id))
    ).pipe(tap(questions => { console.log(questions) }));  // Here you can change the data structure of questions instead of just logging them
}
```

Comment: When I try that, I'm getting a  _Type 'Observable<Question[] | Question[][]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Question[]>'._  exception.

Comment: That's not an exception, it's a type error. You can map your results to anything you want. Try with `pipe(map(questions => questions.flat()))`