# What should be sequence of execution of the code in Angular9?

Tags: typescript, angular9

I have one question. There is code for one function in Angular9, and for some reason it is not executed in the row

```
this.selected.forEach(element => {
  this.entryClient.update(<UpdateEntryCommand>{
    id: element.id,
    accepted: this.newEntryEditor.accepted,
    rejected: this.newEntryEditor.rejected,
    errorId: this.newEntryEditor.errorId
  }).subscribe(() => {
    counter++;
    console.log(element.id);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error.reponse);
  });
});
console.log(counter);
```

For some reason first execute console.log(counter), than go to this.selected...
May some one explain me why ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The this.entryClient.update returns a rxjs Observable so it is asynchronous.

The this.selected.forEach creates all of these Promises and then the console.log(counter) is executed before the first this.entryClient.update is completed.

Comment: Thanks, for explanation. How than I should manage to finish all updates and than console.log(counter) ?

Comment: Have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564529/rxjs-combining-multiple-calls-from-foreach-into-a-single-observable